# TableSorter Custom Parser not sorting correctly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, sorting, tablesorter

I'm trying to write a custom parser for TableSorter that will allow me to sort letter grades dynamically across several headers in an HTML5 table. I googled like crazy and couldn't find an example of this being done already.

I am new to this, but think this could be very helpful for doing classroom sorting, QA reporting, etc. Here I am sorting Free2Work rankings of brands into something I can use on my smartphone.

There are at least two problems here:

1. I got one working in Firefox, but when I load it in Chrome the sort appears random. I'm sure I'm loading the wrong things into the array somewhere, but I'm not sure what it is.
2. The "rating" column sorts properly in Firefox, but it looks like the other columns are not. Same parser for all columns.

Here's the JavaScript I'm using:

```
       $.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: 'grades',
            is: function(s) {
                    return false;
            },
            format: function(s) {
                    // format your data for normalization
                    return s.toLowerCase()
                            .replace("a+",12)
                            .replace("a",11)
                            .replace("a-",10)
                            .replace("b+",09)
                            .replace("b",08)
                            .replace("b-",07)
                            .replace("c+",06)
                            .replace("c",05)
                            .replace("c-",04)
                            .replace("d+",03)
                            .replace("d",02)
                            .replace("d-",01)
                            .replace("f",00);
            },
            type: 'numeric'
    });

    $(function() {
            $('#brands').tablesorter({
                    headers: {
                            2: {sorter:'grades'},
                            3: {sorter:'grades'},
                            4: {sorter:'grades'},
                            5: {sorter:'grades'},
                            6: {sorter:'grades'}
                    }
            });
    });
```

And here's the [truncated] html.

```
<table id="brands" class="tablesorter table striped">
    <caption>
        Brand Ratings
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Logo</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th class="extractor-select sorter-grades">Rating</th>
            <th class="extractor-select sorter-grades">Policy</th>
            <th class="extractor-select sorter-grades">Honesty</th>
            <th class="extractor-select sorter-grades">Monitor</th>
            <th class="extractor-select sorter-grades">Workers</th>
            <th>More</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="brand-logo"></td>
            <td class="brand-name">Etiko</td>
            <td class="brand-overall-grade aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="a">A</td>
            <td class="aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="score-card-button">
                <a href="http://widgets.free2work.org/frontend_ratings/public_view/1268">Scorecard</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="brand-logo"></td>
            <td class="brand-name">Pants to Poverty</td>
            <td class="brand-overall-grade aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="a">A</td>
            <td class="aplus">A+</td>
            <td class="score-card-button">
                <a href="http://widgets.free2work.org/frontend_ratings/public_view/1270">Scorecard</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="brand-logo"><img src="http://widgets.free2work.org/images/Brand/playtex_logo_black0.jpg"></td>
            <td class="brand-name">Playtex</td>
            <td class="brand-overall-grade a">A</td>
            <td class="aminus">A-</td>
            <td class="a">A</td>
            <td class="a">A</td>
            <td class="aminus">A-</td>
            <td class="score-card-button">
                <a href="http://widgets.free2work.org/frontend_ratings/public_view/458">Scorecard</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="brand-logo"><img src="http://widgets.free2work.org/images/Brand/Hanes_Logo0.jpg"></td>
            <td class="brand-name">Hanes</td>
            <td class="brand-overall-grade a">A</td>
            <td class="aminus">A-</td>
            <td class="a">A</td>
            <td class="a">A</td>
            <td class="aminus">A-</td>
            <td class="score-card-button">
                <a href="http://widgets.free2work.org/frontend_ratings/public_view/456">Scorecard</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="brand-logo"></td>
            <td class="brand-name">Voodoo Hosiery</td>
            <td class="brand-overall-grade b">B</td>
            <td class="aminus">A-</td>
            <td class="bminus">B-</td>
            <td class="b">B</td>
            <td class="d">D</td>
            <td class="score-card-button">
                <a href="http://widgets.free2work.org/frontend_ratings/public_view/1077">Scorecard</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="brand-logo"><img src="http://widgets.free2work.org/images/Brand/AmericanBodyArmor0.jpg"></td>
            <td class="brand-name">American Body Armor</td>
            <td class="brand-overall-grade f">F</td>
            <td class="f">F</td>
            <td class="f">F</td>
            <td class="f">F</td>
            <td class="f">F</td>
            <td class="score-card-button">
                <a href="http://widgets.free2work.org/frontend_ratings/public_view/750">Scorecard</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyone have any insight into how I've misconstructed something here? I'm in a bit over my head.

Comment: Here's a fiddle, if anyone's interested: https://jsfiddle.net/01eL3a6w/1/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the demo is using two versions of tablesorter, the [original tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) (v2.0.5) included in the javascript frame (at the bottom) and my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) loaded from a CDN. They both use the same parser code, so that isn't an issue.

But, there are two issues with the custom parser code ([fixed demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/01eL3a6w/2/)):

- When the replace is done, it is being replaced by a digit (numeric value), but it's really still a string. So I wrapped the values in quotes otherwise the leading zero will be removed. This isn't a problem with the fork of tablesorter since it uses a natural sort, but the original uses a standard sort which doesn't sort numbers inside of strings as you would expect.
- Because we're actually dealing with strings, the parser type needs to be changed to "text"

Here is an updated parser cdoe:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'grades',
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    // format your data for normalization
    return s.toLowerCase()
      .replace("a+", '12')
      .replace("a", '11')
      .replace("a-", '10')
      .replace("b+", '09')
      .replace("b", '08')
      .replace("b-", '07')
      .replace("c+", '06')
      .replace("c", '05')
      .replace("c-", '04')
      .replace("d+", '03')
      .replace("d", '02')
      .replace("d-", '01')
      .replace("f", '00');
  },
  type: 'text'
});
```

Another method, which doesn't require set numeric values, adds the values to an array and then uses `indexOf` (or jQuery `$.inArray` if you need to support old IE) to get the position. That parser would be of a "numeric" type ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/b4gfc5y8/))

```
// put grades outside of the format function, so the split
// only needs to happen once
var grades = 'a+ a a- b+ b b- c+ c c- d+ d d- f'.split(' ');

$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'grades',
  is: function(s) {
        return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    var val = $.inArray( ( s || '' ).toLowerCase(), grades );
    // return string if it isn't a grade (to allow sorting)
    return val > -1 ? val : s;
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});
```

One last note on the differences between the original and fork is how to set the parser

- The original only allows setting the column parser within the `headers` option.

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('#brands').tablesorter({
          headers: {
              2: {sorter:'grades'},
              3: {sorter:'grades'},
              4: {sorter:'grades'},
              5: {sorter:'grades'},
              6: {sorter:'grades'}
          }
      });
  });
  ```
- The fork still works with setting the sorter in the `headers` option, but the sorter can also be set using class names on the header

  ```
  <th class="extractor-select sorter-grades">Rating</th>
  ```

  * Note: The "extractor-select" in the class name won't work unless every cell contains a `<select>` element AND the `parser-input-select.js` file is loaded.